# adding comments to a couchdb design doc

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Is there a way to enter comments into a couchdb design doc?

The queries can get pretty cryptic, and it would be really nice to be able to write a brief human description of what they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add comments to your JS code, that's fine.

```
function (doc) {
  // comments are ok here
  if (doc.type === 'user') emit(doc.username);
}
```

However, you can't add comments to the outer JSON, since JSON doesn't support comments.

```
{
  "views": {
    "by-name": {
      // you can't put comments here
      "map": "function (doc) { ..."
    }
  }
}
```